# c structures and pointer allocation pthread

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, structure

I am doing an assignment where I have to process some images with `pthreads` C.

I have the following structures:

```
typedef struct {
    int type;
    int width;
    int height;
    int max_value;
    int *input;
}image;
```

and

```
typedef struct {
    int id; // thread id
    image *in; //input image
}ptf_arguments;
```

I also have a function where I try to instantiate an array of structure_b and assign a argument given structure_a to each of those

```
void resize(image *in, image * out) {
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[num_threads];
    ptf_arguments *arguments[num_threads];
    arguments[0]->in->input = (int *)malloc(in->width * in->height * sizeof(int));
    arguments[0]->in = in; // HERE

    printf("First thread should have id = %d. In image of (%d)\n", arguments[0]->id, arguments[0]->in->width); //here
    for(i = 0 ; i < num_threads; i++) {
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, resize_thread_function, &(arguments[i]));
    }
}
```

1) I don't understand structures very well and i need someone to explain to me how i can pass the in/out images to my ptf_arguments structure so i can pass it to the pthreads function.

2) Do I need to allocate memory for the image struct ?

3) Do I need to allocate memory for the `int` array inside the image struct of the ptf_arguments struct ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When I read the code, I see

```
ptf_arguments *arguments[num_threads];
arguments[0]->in->undefined behavior
```

You need to point `in` at a valid `image` structure before dereferencing it. The simplest way is probably to move the line you tagged `//HERE` up above the previous line.

Yes, you also need to allocate an array of `int` and point the `input` member of the `image` structure at that memory. Needless to say, you'll need to do this initialization and allocation for each `ptf_arguments` object, not just the first.

I think your syntax for passing the address of a single `ptf_arguments` object is fine.

Answer (score 0):

A structure is basically an object that you can't change subparts of.
It's mostly like a Javascript variable. You access its subparts with a dot `varname.subpartname` if the variable is plain, with the arrow `varname->subpart` if it's a pointer.

Structures are variables types. You don't have to allocate memory to them (except if using pointers...)

Each subpart must be initialized depending on their type. Therefore, pointer subparts must be `malloc`'ed exactly like any pointer, or defined with an existing pointer.

```C
void resize(image *in, image * out) {
    pthread_t tid[num_threads];
    ptf_arguments *arguments[num_threads];
//    arguments[0]->in->input = malloc(in->width * in->height * sizeof(int));
//The preceding line is useless (and also using an uninitialized item). You already have a complete pointer.
    arguments[0]->in = in; // HERE

    printf("First thread should have id = %d. In image of (%d)\n", arguments[0]->id, arguments[0]->in->width); //here
    for(int i = 0 ; i < num_threads; i++) {//Since you only use int i here, you can declare it in the for condition
        pthread_create(&(tid[i]), NULL, resize_thread_function, &(arguments[i]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1) I don't understand structures very well and i need someone to explain to me how i can pass the in/out images to my ptf_arguments structure so i can pass it to the pthreads function.

If you need 1 struct per thread, pass it to `pthread_create` by address, by using the `arg` parameter. Just like you already attempted: `&(arguments[i])`. You probably meant to just do `arguments[i]` though, since this is a pointer. You are actually not passing the address allocated data, but the address of the local pointer, which is bad and incorrect.

IMPORTANT: You should never pass a pointer to a local variable to a thread! The variable needs to be allocated with either static storage duration, or through dynamic allocation.

If you don't "understand structures very well" you should probably study them and practice using them a lot more, before moving on to advanced topics like multi-threading. In general, you can't program by trial & error, you actually need to know what every line typed does. There's no "take a chance".

> 2) Do i need to allocate memory for the image struct ?

Yes. And that's another reason why your code doesn't work. `ptf_arguments *arguments[num_threads];` is just an array of pointers, no memory for the actual data is allocated.

> > 3) Do i need to allocate memory for the int array inside the image struct of the ptf_arguments struct ?

Yes.

Also remember to `free` all memory when done using it. A function called "resize" should probably not allocate resources unless it frees up previously used resources first.